# Combining Autumn Ale and Apfelwein

Tags: cider, ale

I’d like to brew a spiced Autumn Ale, but somehow also combine it with Apfelwein. Can this be done? Sort of, a bastardized version of Graf (Graaf / Graff) Recipe I have calls for adding “pure apple flavor” during priming, and I thought, hey, WTF, maybe use a Apfelwein, instead? Any other way come to anyone’s mind? Could this be done during fermentation? Could you add something already fermented with a considerable ABV to an ale still in fermentation?

Comment: Sure you can do that, it's homebrewing after all! You'll have to experiment and figure out the details (how much apple wine will give you the taste you want). If you had an extremely high alcohol level and add a lot of that booze, it may harm the beer yeast --- do some research here, some wine yeasts die at around 12 or 15 %ABV, and I don't know how much beer yeasts can take.